# make a website invisible externally

Tags: iis, web, firewall

I have a webserver (IIS) that is both reachable externally and internally.

A few websites on it are also reachable internally and externally.

Now I want to create a new site, that only can be reached internally.

I don't want to work with username/password due to security reasons.

Can this be done in the firewall, of any other options?

Thx!

Comment: If you use IIS, all your data are freely accessible internally and externally anyway, so why bother? ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Windows Authentication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754628%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), so only internal users can access the site.